# Gradle sync failed: cannot detect java version

Tags: java, android, jdk, android-studio, android-sdk

Im running ubuntu 14.04.3
I installed android studio using:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/adroid-studio`

and installed the oracle jdk 8 using:

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

however when I run Android studios it tells me:

`Gradle sync failed: cannot detect java version.`

Ive been looking around for a while and have no idea how to fix that. 
I will add that I am pretty new to ubuntu and android studios so I don't now exactly what I'm doing. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

dont forget

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

and always

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after installing anything new